# unwanted multiple launch of app in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have an application (Thunderbird) that opens 4 times whenever launched, whether it is from the pin or desktop shortcut. I don't know how I have achieved this, but wish I hadn't! How can I resume my boring one-click = one-launch method of working?

Comment: I assume running the EXE directly only launches a single copy? If so, try pinning it anew.